# Issue in openning an app on iphone and submitting the same page

Tags: javascript, html, ios

This is what am trying to do. I have a webpage, which has a link, on click of which it should automatically open an app {which has a URI scheme} on iphone, and also submit the page.

the only way i could find out is to open the app through an iframe {iframe.src=appid://}, and submit the page {document.formname.submit()}. this works properly on mobile safari; but not on chrome.

on chrome the app opens up, but the page from where the app was openned does not submit.

Any idea, how this needs to be handled, across phones and browsers would be of great help?

Comment: Why don't you on set the URL when the postback is finished and returned to the client? Or make the form request an Ajax call and oncomplete, navigate to the URL. Make it two steps, not one.

Comment: hi epascarello,Did not get you. Its a two step process. 1- openning the app , 2- submitting the document. the page on submission goes to a server whichintructs it to go to a different page. Can be kind enough to write the code as to what you are saying, or point me to a reference code?